# Console application using Clipboard.GetFileDropList: how to check if that came from a cut or copy operation?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

When you cut/copy files from [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer), you can get that list of files through the [Clipboard.GetFileDropList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getfiledroplist) method.

How can you determine if that list came from a `cut` or `copy` operation or notify the other party that the cut/copy operation finished?

The other way around: you can put files to be cut or copied on the clipboard using the [Clipboard.SetFileDropList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setfiledroplist) method.

How can you specify that this list is to be copied or cut?

This is about a console application, so I cannot monitor the Windows `WM_CUT` or `WM_COPY` messages as suggested by [C# Files - in clipboard How to set/read which operation is called - Cut or Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813378/c-sharp-files-in-clipboard-how-to-set-read-which-operation-is-called-cut-or/4813548#4813548)

Comment: I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69820983/2956830

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value for the "Preferred DropEffect" format (see [CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT)). It contains a `STGMEDIUM` whose `hGlobal` field points to a DWORD value. If this value is `DROPEFFECT_COPY`, it's a copy operation; if it's `DROPEFFECT_MOVE`, it's a cut operation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go and try this and get back with feedback hopefully later this week (some pressing work came in between me and this research project).