# Implement Cut and Copy functions to Winforms app from Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, copy-paste, windows-explorer

I am trying to implement paste operations in my winforms app that were being cut or copied in windows explorer and vice versa. I already have a working cut and copy functionality within the application but I need to be able to also detect cut and copy operations done in windows explorer and being able to paste while using my app.

My app is basically a self-made file explorer consisting of a listview and treeview. I have done some research and so far have failed to find a solution, hence this question.

I took a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20613291/7503422) and I don't know how I can read the mentioned `CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT` or how Windows Explorer actually knows if a paste operation is a Move or Copy.

My goal is to be able to perform a paste operation from a cut or copy command that the user invoked in Windows Explorer in my application while knowing whether the intended execution is a copy or a move. I know that there is a `Clipboard` class which has `SetFileDropList()` and `GetFileDropList()` but those methods do not tell me if the user wishes to cut or copy the files in the clipboard. Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 0):

This post seem would appear to solve youre problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889962/6450641